# Using third party library with react js giving error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, nouislider, bootstrap-tags-input

I am trying to use third party plugins like bootstrap-tagsinout and noUiSlider in my react application. I have installed the libraries via npm to my package.json. Currently I am initializing the plugins in my componentDidMount method. This is how I do it

```
componentDidMount = () => {

        $(document).ready(function() {
            // Apply the plugin to the element
            $("#ionSlider-newTag").ionRangeSlider({
                min: 0,
                max: 5000,
                type: 'double',
                postfix: 's',
                maxPostfix: "+",
                prettify: false,
                hasGrid: true,
                from: 1600,
                to: 2950
            });
        });

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#tagsinput').tagsinput({
                typeahead: {
                    source: ['Smoking, Drinking, Eating']
                }
            });
        });

        $(document).ready(function() {
            // Apply the plugin to the element
            $("#noUiSlider").noUiSlider({
                start: 40,
                connect: "lower",
                range: {
                    'min': 0,
                    'max': 100
                }
            });
        });
```

And here is my div for tagsinput

```
<div className="form-group form-group-default">
                                        <label>Tags</label>
                                        <input id="#tagsinput" type="text" value="Smoking,Drinking" data-role="tagsinput"/>
                                    </div>
```

When I run it, i get an error saying

```
index.js:121 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tagsinput is not a function
```

and

```
index.js:121 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).noUiSlider is not a function
```

I imported the plugins in my react component

```
import 'ion-rangeslider'
import 'bootstrap-tagsinput'
import 'nouislider'
import $ from 'jquery'
```

I have looked for all the question already existing and tried them. But nothing worked. What an I doing wrong?

Update

I tried using refs, but didn't help

```
 <input id="#tagsinput" type="text"  ref={(input) => {textInput = input; }}  value="Smoking,Drinking" data-role="tagsinput"/>

textInput.tagsinput({
                typeahead: {
                    source: ['Smoking, Drinking, Eating']
                }
            });
```

But I am getting this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tagsinput' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery within a react component is not recommended, because of the way React handles the virtual DOM and diffing.  In short React tracks elements in the DOM and adds / removes / updates them when appropriate and performant.  As a result the elements you're looking for with jQuery may not exist in the DOM yet.  Also the `$(document).ready...` wrapper is not being run until the component is mounted, and thus the document `ready` event has probably fired before the jQuery is run.

You'll want to look into using React `refs` to get access to DOM elements in React: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: Please have a look at the update added in my ques. That didn't work :(

Comment: You'll need to attach your input to the component when using a ref: 
`ref={ (input) => {this.textInput = input} }`.  You can then reference the DOM node with `this.textInput`.  Note that it will not necessarily give you access to jQuery methods for reasons stated in the original answer.

Comment: I used this.textInput, but it was not refering to textInput variable. When I used just textInput it started refereing to variable. Strange. But can you please tell me the best way to use this plugin with react?

Answer (score 0):

As from facebook example:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  ...
  this.myRef = React.createRef();
}
```

In render():
`return <input  ref={this.myRef}  ...`

In componentDidMount():

```
this.myRef.current.someEvent = this.eventHandler;
```

Or

```
this.myRef.current.tagsinput({ ...
```

It works for me